# Using Django ORM to query a Model with two FKs that are related through an unique_together constraint on a third Model

Tags: sql, django, django-models, orm, django-queryset

I am currently facing a challenge in creating a QuerySet that accurately represents the relationships within my Django models. I have a model equipped with two foreign keys, FK1 and FK2. These two foreign keys, when combined, create a tuple representing a classification (FK1, FK2 -> CLS.pk).
This relationship is managed and represented through another model, where I store the records corresponding to these foreign keys and the resulting classification (FK1, FK2, CLS.pk).

Defining my question has been a challenge in itself, so I've tried to simplify the relationship to illustrate the core idea of what I'm attempting to achieve here.

```
class Event(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=11, default=0.0)
    event_date = models.DateField()
    local = models.ForeignKey(Local, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_set')
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Origin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='event_set')

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'db_event'
        
class Local(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'db_local'
        
class Origin(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'db_origin'
        
class Classification(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'db_classification'
        
class ClassificationPerOriginAndLocal(models.Model):
    local = models.ForeignKey(Local, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classification_related_set')
    origin = models.ForeignKey(Origin, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classification_related_set')
    classification = models.ForeignKey(Classification, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='classification_related_set')
    
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'db_classification_per_origin_and_local'
        unique_together = ('local', 'origin',)
```

Consider an 'Event' Model designed to store records for events occurring at a specific origin and in a specific local. Later on I need to classify each event and this classification is achieved through the tuple 'origin' and 'local'.

This classification system is managed through a third model called 'ClassificationPerOriginAndLocal', where I specify which 'Classification' object corresponds to a given pair of 'origin' and 'local' objects.

In a SQL raw query, I would formulate something like this to obtain the 'Classification.pk':

```
SELECT
        ev.*,
        clsf.classification_id
    FROM db_event as ev 
    INNER JOIN db_classification_per_origin_and_local as clsf
     ON clsf.local_id = ev.local_id
      AND clsf.origin_id = ev.origin_id
```

How can I use (if it's possible) the Django ORM to create this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long time digging through other Stack Overflow threads and the Django documentation, I managed to resolve this issue by using [Subquery and OuterRef](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/expressions/):

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

# Creating the subquery
subquery = (
    ClassificationPerOriginAndLocal
    .objects
    .filter(local=OuterRef('local'), origin=OuterRef('origin'))
)

# Constructing the final query with annotation
final_query = (
    Event
    .objects
    .annotate(classification=Subquery(subquery.values('classification')))
)
```

For context, the solution I found ensures that the subquery only returns a singular value per relation (local + origin -> classification). This is enforced by leveraging the unique constraint for local + origin (set using unique_together).

Moreover, if you need to access specific fields within the classification object, you can achieve this using Django's '__' lookups:

```
final_query = (
    Event
    .objects
    .annotate(
        classification=Subquery(subquery.values('classification')),
        classification__name=Subquery(subquery.values('classification__name')
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.db.models import F

events_with_classification = Event.objects.annotate(
    classification_id=F('local__classification_related_set__classification_id')
)

# Now, you can access the classification_id field for each Event object
for event in events_with_classification:
    classification_id = event.classification_id
```

You should be able to access the 'classification_id' field for each 'Event' in the queryset, and it will contain the 'Classification.pk' as specified in your 'ClassificationPerOriginAndLocal' model.

Comment: This annotation just solves one of the relations.
'local' can have different 'classification' objects for different 'origin'.
Its both together that define the relation (local + origin -> distinct classification).